# How to create a forum with posts and replies for each post

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I have a forum page with users' posts. I need to make a reply text area where a user can reply to any post. the problem is whenever a post is replied to, my JS script is unable to detect the specific post that the reply belongs to.

Here is the php snippet that generates a list of the posts and creates a reply form.

```html
echo'
<div id="div'.$post_id.'"></div>
<form name="form'.$post_id.'">'; echo'
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <img src="" width="70" height="70" class="img img-responsive" alt="Your profile picture.">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <textarea placeholder="Your reply" name="user_reply" class="form-control" maxlength="250" rows="3" required></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$userId .'">
      <input type="hidden" name="time" value="'.$time .'">
      <input type="hidden" name="date" value="'.$date .'">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <button name="data" type="button" onclick="sendReply(\' '.$post_id.' \');">Reply</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>';
```

Now here is the JS script that I think should pick the user's reply and send the values to reply.php file

```html
<script>
 function sendReply(id){
  x='document.form'+id;
  post_id = id;
  user_id = x.user_id.value;
  reply = x.user_reply.value;
  date = x.date.value;
  time = x.time.value;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{
   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }
  
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
    document.getElementById("div"+id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
  }
  xmlhttp.open('GET', 'reply.php?reply='+reply+'&post_id='+post_id+'&user_id='+user_id+'&time='+time+'&date='+date, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

 }
</script>
```

Finally here is the error I am getting in the browser console when I click the reply button

```html
(index):121 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefinedsendReply
@ (index):121onclick 
@ VM161:211
```

Comment: I think you should definitely check some of the good tutorials that already exist. Like [this one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch--net-10188).
Regarding your question, it says that it cant read property 'value' of undefined. Reason for that is because of this `x='document.form'+id;
` where x evaluates to simple string - so x.user_id doesnt exist and also x.user_id.value doesn't exist .What you want is to get the form from the page and then access its elements. You can get list of all forms with x = document.forms;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is the problem:

```
x='document.form'+id;
post_id = id;
user_id = x.user_id.value;
```

Here you're creating a variable `x` that contains a string, but then you try to access it as if it was an object.

Instead, try this:

```
x = document['form' + id]
```